Vaadin: c.v.b.devserver.DebugWindowConnection : Connection denied because of a missing or invalid token. The host is probably not on the allow list
I have a little demo application written in Kotlin/Java using Vaadin Flow 24.3.7 with SpringDevTools 3.2.4.
When I start the app in development mode I get warnings on the console saying:
c.v.b.devserver.DebugWindowConnection    : Connection denied because of a missing or invalid token. The host is probably not on the allow list
Any ideas what to change to get rid of this warnings?
Thank you and best regards,
Frank

Have you checked devmode.hostsAllowed property?
More info on
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode/dev-tools
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/properties#properties

I've added the wrong IP respectively the IP-Pattern was too strict. It seems to work for now. Thank you.
